# Dimension expanding for loop (python)

Tags: python, for-loop

How do I program a for loop in python where each new instance gets assigned to a new dimension/column in python (numpy array)? Say:

```
y=[0,1,2]
z=numpy.zero(3,3)
for i in range(3):
z[i,:]=sin(i*math.pi*2-y)
```

Wouldn't work. I want the output array to be:

```
1: sin(0*math.pi*2-0)          2: sin(0*math.pi*2-1)             3: sin(0*math.pi*2-2)
4: sin(1*math.pi*2-0)          5: sin(1*math.pi*2-1)             6: sin(1*math.pi*2-2)
7: sin(2*math.pi*2-0)          6: sin(2*math.pi*2-1)             9: sin(2*math.pi*2-2)
```

The indexes are just for separating the terms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code.
The below should work:

```
import numpy
import math

y=[0,1,2]
z=numpy.zeros((3,3))
for i in range(3):
    z[i,:] = math.sin(i*math.pi*2-y[i])
```

Comment: The values are not actually same but the difference is so minimal between the values that they seem same.
You can try with some different values to confirm the same.

Comment: @Shabalah Aggarwal Aha, I was wondering more about the principle (since the real code I am working with has 100s of rows and columns, this was just an example). I found the solution though, construct a loop "for a in range(3):" on the row before the loop, indent the original for loop and replace "[i,:]" with [i,a] and one i with an a.